No Planning Library Loaded
i am using ros2 humble
i have build moveit2 from source
when I try to run my demo.launch.py I am getting like this but when I run moveit2 tutorial pandas it works fine without any issue and event it states within 5 secs but when I launch my package it takes around 3 to 5 mins, I am not able find the issues can anyone help me with this


this is my launch file
import os
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch.conditions import IfCondition, UnlessCondition
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch.actions import ExecuteProcess
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from moveit_configs_utils import MoveItConfigsBuilder
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare

def generate_launch_description():

    package_name_ = 'kelvin6kpro_moveit_config'
    pkg_share_ = FindPackageShare(package=package_name_).find(package_name_)
    rviz_config_file_path = os.path.join(pkg_share_, 'rviz/moveit.rviz')

    ros2_control_hardware_type = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        "ros2_control_hardware_type",
        default_value="mock_components",
        description="ROS2 control hardware interface type to use for the launch file -- possible values: [mock_components, isaac]",
    )

    moveit_config = (
        MoveItConfigsBuilder("kelvin6kpro")
        .robot_description(
            file_path="config/kelvin6kpro.urdf.xacro",
            mappings={
                "ros2_control_hardware_type": LaunchConfiguration(
                    "ros2_control_hardware_type"
                )
            },
        )
        .robot_description_semantic(file_path="config/kelvin6kpro.srdf",)
        .trajectory_execution(file_path="config/moveit_controllers.yaml")
        .planning_pipelines(
            pipelines=["pilz_industrial_motion_planner"]
        )
        .to_moveit_configs()
    )

    # Start the actual move_group node/action server
    move_group_node = Node(
        package="moveit_ros_move_group",
        executable="move_group",
        output="screen",
        parameters=[moveit_config.to_dict()],
        arguments=["--ros-args", "--log-level", "info"],
    )

    rviz_node = Node(
        package="rviz2",
        executable="rviz2",
        name="rviz2",
        output="log",
        arguments=["-d", rviz_config_file_path],
        parameters=[
            moveit_config.robot_description,
            moveit_config.robot_description_semantic,
            moveit_config.robot_description_kinematics,
            moveit_config.planning_pipelines,
            moveit_config.joint_limits,
        ],
    )

    # Static TF
    static_tf_node = Node(
        package="tf2_ros",
        executable="static_transform_publisher",
        name="static_transform_publisher",
        output="log",
        arguments=["0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "world", "base_link"],
    )

    # Publish TF
    robot_state_publisher = Node(
        package="robot_state_publisher",
        executable="robot_state_publisher",
        name="robot_state_publisher",
        output="both",
        parameters=[moveit_config.robot_description],
    )

    # ros2_control using FakeSystem as hardware
    ros2_controllers_path = os.path.join(
        get_package_share_directory("kelvin6kpro_moveit_config"),
        "config",
        "ros2_controllers.yaml",
    )
    
    ros2_control_node = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="ros2_control_node",
        parameters=[ros2_controllers_path],
        remappings=[
            ("/controller_manager/robot_description", "/robot_description"),
        ],
        output="screen",
    )

    joint_state_broadcaster_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=[
            "joint_state_broadcaster",
            "--controller-manager",
            "/controller_manager",
        ],
    )

    kelvin6kpro_controller_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=["kelvin6kpro_controller", "-c", "/controller_manager"],
    )

    """   kelvin6kpro_hopper_controller_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=["kelvin6kpro_hopper_controller", "-c", "/controller_manager"],
    ) """

    return LaunchDescription(
        [   ros2_control_hardware_type,
            move_group_node,
            rviz_node,
            static_tf_node,
            robot_state_publisher,
            ros2_control_node,
            joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
            kelvin6kpro_controller_spawner,

        ]
    )

this is the log in terminal I get
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/ros2/.ros/log/2024-11-20-16-45-27-045325-Kelvin6k-184400
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [move_group-1]: process started with pid [184402]
[INFO] [rviz2-2]: process started with pid [184404]
[INFO] [static_transform_publisher-3]: process started with pid [184408]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-4]: process started with pid [184410]
[INFO] [ros2_control_node-5]: process started with pid [184412]
[INFO] [spawner-6]: process started with pid [184414]
[INFO] [spawner-7]: process started with pid [184417]
[static_transform_publisher-3] [WARN] [1732101327.337300786] []: Old-style arguments are deprecated; see --help for new-style arguments
[static_transform_publisher-3] [INFO] [1732101327.350333870] [static_transform_publisher]: Spinning until stopped - publishing transform
[static_transform_publisher-3] translation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-3] rotation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000', '1.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-3] from 'world' to 'base_link'
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1732101327.362667709] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1732101327.362797770] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment x_axis
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1732101327.362809188] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment y_axis
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1732101327.362815239] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment z_axis_p1
[robot_state_publisher-4] [INFO] [1732101327.362820508] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment z_axis_p2
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1732101327.383696407] [controller_manager]: Subscribing to '~/robot_description' topic for robot description file.
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1732101327.384523525] [controller_manager]: update rate is 100 Hz
[ros2_control_node-5] [WARN] [1732101327.384704200] [controller_manager]: No real-time kernel detected on this system. See [https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_control/controller_manager/doc/userdoc.html] for details on how to enable realtime scheduling.
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1732101327.387678857] [controller_manager]: Received robot description file.
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1732101327.387912450] [resource_manager]: Loading hardware 'FakeSystem'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1732101327.388636227] [resource_manager]: Initialize hardware 'FakeSystem'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1732101327.388788167] [resource_manager]: Successful initialization of hardware 'FakeSystem'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1732101327.388857240] [resource_manager]: 'configure' hardware 'FakeSystem'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1732101327.388871050] [resource_manager]: Successful 'configure' of hardware 'FakeSystem'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1732101327.388879267] [resource_manager]: 'activate' hardware 'FakeSystem'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1732101327.388887441] [resource_manager]: Successful 'activate' of hardware 'FakeSystem'
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1732101327.398726999] [moveit_rdf_loader.rdf_loader]: Loaded robot model in 0.00334697 seconds
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1732101327.398847765] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'kelvin6kpro'...
[rviz2-2] QStandardPaths: wrong permissions on runtime directory /run/user/1000/, 0755 instead of 0700
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1732101327.634387754] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1732101327.634631194] [rviz2]: OpenGl version: 4.5 (GLSL 4.5)
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1732101327.683115816] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1732101327.715633083] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'kelvin6kpro_controller'
[ros2_control_node-5] [WARN] [1732101327.734282293] [kelvin6kpro_controller]: [Deprecated]: "allow_nonzero_velocity_at_trajectory_end" is set to true. The default behavior will change to false.
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1732101327.749885813] [spawner_kelvin6kpro_controller]: Loaded kelvin6kpro_controller
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1732101327.751660933] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'kelvin6kpro_controller'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1732101327.751913425] [kelvin6kpro_controller]: No specific joint names are used for command interfaces. Using 'joints' parameter.
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1732101327.751946069] [kelvin6kpro_controller]: Command interfaces are [position] and state interfaces are [position velocity].
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1732101327.752019228] [kelvin6kpro_controller]: Using 'splines' interpolation method.
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1732101327.753015107] [kelvin6kpro_controller]: Controller state will be published at 50.00 Hz.
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1732101327.757336991] [kelvin6kpro_controller]: Action status changes will be monitored at 20.00 Hz.
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1732101327.785905514] [spawner_kelvin6kpro_controller]: Configured and activated kelvin6kpro_controller
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1732101327.816232559] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1732101327.840407675] [moveit_rdf_loader.rdf_loader]: Loaded robot model in 0.00291815 seconds
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1732101327.840501502] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'kelvin6kpro'...
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1732101327.849510170] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Loaded joint_state_broadcaster
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1732101327.851088443] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1732101327.851280867] [joint_state_broadcaster]: 'joints' or 'interfaces' parameter is empty. All available state interfaces will be published
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1732101327.876736912] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Configured and activated joint_state_broadcaster
[INFO] [spawner-7]: process has finished cleanly [pid 184417]
[INFO] [spawner-6]: process has finished cleanly [pid 184414]
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1732101345.818413221] [moveit_rdf_loader.rdf_loader]: Loaded robot model in 0.00146724 seconds
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1732101345.818499808] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'kelvin6kpro'...
[rviz2-2] Warning: class_loader.impl: SEVERE WARNING!!! A namespace collision has occurred with plugin factory for class rviz_default_plugins::displays::InteractiveMarkerDisplay. New factory will OVERWRITE existing one. This situation occurs when libraries containing plugins are directly linked against an executable (the one running right now generating this message). Please separate plugins out into their own library or just don't link against the library and use either class_loader::ClassLoader/MultiLibraryClassLoader to open.
[rviz2-2]          at line 253 in /opt/ros/humble/include/class_loader/class_loader/class_loader_core.hpp
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1732101357.075860241] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Publishing maintained planning scene on 'monitored_planning_scene'
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1732101357.081093732] [moveit.ros_planning_interface.moveit_cpp]: Listening to 'joint_states' for joint states
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1732101357.086719566] [moveit_ros.current_state_monitor]: Listening to joint states on topic 'joint_states'
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1732101357.088139781] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/attached_collision_object' for attached collision objects
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1732101357.088198728] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting planning scene monitor
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1732101357.089210923] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/planning_scene'
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1732101357.089388506] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting world geometry update monitor for collision objects, attached objects, octomap updates.
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1732101357.090186234] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to 'collision_object'
[move_group-1] [INFO] [1732101357.091133292] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to 'planning_scene_world' for planning scene world geometry
[move_group-1] [WARN] [1732101357.125304805] [moveit.ros.occupancy_map_monitor.middleware_handle]: Resolution not specified for Octomap. Assuming resolution = 0.1 instead
[move_group-1] [ERROR] [1732101357.125379310] [moveit.ros.occupancy_map_monitor.middleware_handle]: No 3D sensor plugin(s) defined for octomap updates
[rviz2-2] [ERROR] [1732101357.476908255] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: Action server: /recognize_objects not available
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1732101357.552144380] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: MoveGroup namespace changed: / -> . Reloading params.
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1732101378.868526805] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting planning scene monitor
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1732101378.875127203] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/monitored_planning_scene'
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1732101382.588133401] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting planning scene monitor
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1732101382.591200759] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/monitored_planning_scene'
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1732101382.651834080] [interactive_marker_display_93991423071456]: Connected on namespace: /rviz_moveit_motion_planning_display/robot_interaction_interactive_marker_topic
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1732101383.864945075] [interactive_marker_display_93991423071456]: Sending request for interactive markers
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1732101383.918005669] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Failed to call service get_planning_scene, have you launched move_group or called psm.providePlanningSceneService()?
[rviz2-2] [WARN] [1732101385.028811233] [interactive_marker_display_93991423071456]: Did not receive response with interactive markers, resending request...
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1732101385.028946526] [interactive_marker_display_93991423071456]: Sending request for interactive markers
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1732101385.029064395] [interactive_marker_display_93991423071456]: Service response received for initialization
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1732101386.186023823] [interactive_marker_display_93991423071456]: Service response received for initialization
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1732101387.696923411] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Failed to call service get_planning_scene, have you launched move_group or called psm.providePlanningSceneService()?
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1732101387.697061386] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: group kelvin6kpro_arm
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1732101387.697070916] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: Constructing new MoveGroup connection for group 'kelvin6kpro_arm' in namespace ''
[rviz2-2] [INFO] [1732101446.674736384] [move_group_interface]: Ready to take commands for planning group kelvin6kpro_arm.
[robot_state_publisher-4] [WARN] [1732101483.572756169] [robot_state_publisher]: Moved backwards in time, re-publishing joint transforms!

